# CGAL Segmentation Fault using CGAL::create_offset_polygons_2

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, mingw, cgal

I'm trying the CGAL library. Specifically the straight skeleton package.
I'm getting a segmentation fault when executing one of the simple examples in the documentation and I don't know if it is a possible bug or I am doing something wrong. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

This is the example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>
#include <CGAL/create_offset_polygons_2.h>
//#include "print.h"

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K ;
typedef K::Point_2                   Point ;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K>           Polygon_2 ;
typedef CGAL::Straight_skeleton_2<K> Ss ;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Polygon_2> PolygonPtr ;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Ss> SsPtr ;
typedef std::vector<PolygonPtr> PolygonPtrVector ;

int main()
{
  Polygon_2 poly ;

  poly.push_back( Point(-1,-1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(0,-12) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(1,-1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(12,0) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(1,1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(0,12) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(-1,1) ) ;
  poly.push_back( Point(-12,0) ) ;

  SsPtr ss = CGAL::create_interior_straight_skeleton_2(poly);

  double lOffset = 1 ;

  PolygonPtrVector offset_polygons = CGAL::create_offset_polygons_2<Polygon_2>(lOffset,*ss);

  //print_polygons(offset_polygons);

  return 0;
}
```

The segmentation fault happens when the program ends, in one of the destructors, according to the debugger.
If I comment the line with `create_offset_polygons_2` the program exits normally.
The debugger says that the error happens in the file `Handle.h`in line 62:

```
60  ~Handle()
61  {
62  if ( PTR && (--PTR->count == 0))
63      delete PTR;
64  }
```

This is the stack trace:

```
1  CGAL::Handle::~Handle                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Handle.h 62  0x41d3c4   
2  CGAL::Lazy<CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false>>>, CGAL::Line_2<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>>, CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Cartesian_converter<CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpq>, CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Interval_nt<false>>, CGAL::NT_converter<CGAL::Gmpq, CGAL::Interval_nt<false>>>>::~Lazy Lazy.h   712 0x41ccbf   
3  libstdc++-6!_ZN11__gnu_debug30_Safe_unordered_container_base7_M_swapERS0_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0x6fe5a72a 
4  libstdc++-6!_ZN11__gnu_debug30_Safe_unordered_container_base7_M_swapERS0_                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0x6fe5a780 
5  ??                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x6fe411b4 
6  ??                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x6fe41325 
7  ??                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x6fe41433 
8  ntdll!RtlDecompressBuffer                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0x77eae58e 
9  ntdll!LdrShutdownThread                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0x77e80e46 
10 ??                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      0x6fe41410 
11 ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0x77e6a862 
12 ??
```

I'm using:

- MinGW 32 with gcc 5.3.0 (the one that comes with Qt 5.8)
- CGAL version 4.9.1 with CGAL_HEADER_ONLY option
- Boost version 1.64.0
- libgmp version 6.1.2
- libmpfr version 3.1.5
- The third party libraries are compiled with the same MinGW

Comment: I tried to run on my linux box the example above and it worked. Is it the exact same program? Note that even if MinGW is not officially support I'm a bit surprised by where it is crashing.

Comment: The program is exactly as I posted it here. The only changes I made to the one in CGAL documentation is to comment two lines related to printing the polygons.